Change Database Table prefix to improve security
I always change the WP database Table prefixes to improve security. Can I do the same for the civicrm_tables without causing a problem with the functioning of the Database?

I'm not aware of any security reason for  prefixes. In drupal at least I remember the main reason for prefixes had to do with shared hosting where you only get one database but wanted multiple sites.
The short answer is no. But you can put the civi tables in a separate database. https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/#run-the-installer

I have installed CiviCRM in my WP database, because I am setting up for a small organisation and wished to keep the hosting costs minimal. But, with WP sites, I always change the WP_table prefix to make the DB more secure. My worry was that changing the civi_table prefixes (or the WP_ prefix might cause a problem with the function of the database. I guess I can try-it-and-see, then report back. But if you believe there shouldnt be a securty issue, then I rather not spend the extra time and effor to find out. :)
